# Is pagination possible with table joins in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have tried to insert pagination in multiple table joins using codeigniter but all in vain. I am only be able to fetch the first link and the other links displays empty pages.

Here is the code:

```
public function categoryfour()
{

$config = array();

    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "bulletins/categoryfour";

    $total_row = $this->news_model->record_count_category_four();

    $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;

    $config["per_page"] = 2;

    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;


    $config['num_links'] = $total_row;

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';

    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';

    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';

    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["posts"] =$this->news_model->get_news_cat_four($config["per_page"], $page);

    $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data["pages"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );

    $this->load->view('category_one',$data);
}
```

model is here:

```
function get_news_cat_four($limit, $start)
{

    $this->db->select('news.id as newsId,news_category.id as catId,users.id as userId,news.*,news_category.*,users.*,comments.*, COUNT(comments.post_id) as num_comments');

    $this->db->join('users' , 'users.id = news.user_id');

    $this->db->join('news_category' , 'news_category.cat_id = news.news_id');

    $this->db->join('comments' , 'comments.post_id = news.id');

    $this->db->group_by('comments.post_id');

    $this->db->order_by('news.date_added','desc');

    $this->db->where('news.news_id',4);

    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

    $query = $this->db->get("news");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;}
```

and the view:

```
<div id="page-content" class="single-page container">

    <div class="gutter-7px">

        <div id="main-content" class="col-md-8 fix-right">

            <article class="single-post">

            <?php if(count($posts)) { 

              foreach($posts as $n){ ?>

                <div class="entry-header">

                    <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo base_url('bulletins/view/'.$n->newsId)?>"><?php echo $n->title;?></a></h1>
                    <span> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php echo date( 'F jS, Y g:i a' , strtotime($n->date_added))?>/ 

               <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>

               <?php echo $n->num_comments;?>/<i class="fa fa-user"></i> 

                   <?php echo $n->username?></span>

                </div>
                <div class="post-thumbnail-wrap"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>bulletins/view/<?php echo $n->newsId?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/'.$n->image)?>"
                 style="width:800px;height:500px" /></a></div>

                <div class="entry-content">
                            <p><?php echo  substr(strip_tags($n->content), 0, 200).'...';?></p>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>bulletins/view/<?php echo $n->newsId?>">Read More...</a>
                            <?php }}?>
                            </div>

            </article>
            <div id="pagination">
             <ul class="pagination">

             <!-- Show pagination links -->
             <?php foreach ($pages as $link) {

              echo "<li>". $link."</li>";

               } 
              ?>

            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well you just need to pass on the parameters to the query (use query string)

Comment: Use this to append the parameters: $pager['suffix'] = '&' . $filters; where $filters is the parameters (string) to pass on

Comment: kindly give an example

Comment: I don't see any code, plz update the original question with the code.

Comment: @Just_Do_It check the code I have updated

Comment: Will you be keeping news_id as 4 or will you keep that dynamic?

Comment: @Just_Do_It  the news_id 4 is linked to category 4 where I have so many posts.

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like this to get the results you are seeking (not used your code here):

```
 listOrders($ordering) {

        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $this->load->model('orders_model','orders');
        $this->orders->setLimit(DEFAULT_LIMIT);
        $numRows = $this->orders->countOrders();
        $offset = ($this->uri->segment(4) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(4): 0);
        $orderList = $this->orders->getOrderList($ordering,$offset);

        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/'.$this->language."/recent-orders/".$ordering."/";
        $config['per_page'] = DEFAULT_LIMIT;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $config['num_links'] = 4;
        $config['total_rows'] = $numRows;

        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = $config['next_tag_open'] = $config['prev_tag_open'] = $config['last_tag_open'] = $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = $config['next_tag_close'] = $config['prev_tag_close'] = $config['last_tag_close'] = $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['paging'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        if($data['paging']!= '') {
            $data['paging_caption'] = formatPaginationCaption($this->pagination).$numRows;
        } 

        $data['sortby'] = $ordering;
        $data['offset'] = $offset;              
    }
```

Comment: Thank you . but I have not see your model. Anyway, are you able to detect  any kind of abnormalities from my code.